# what is the space complexity of this program

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

```
def howsum(target, array):


    if target == 0:
        return []

    if target<0:
        return None

    for num in array:

        remainder = target-num

        sol = howsum(remainder, array)

        if sol!=None:
            return [num]+sol


    return None

print(howsum(8,[5,3,2]))
print(howsum(7,[3,2]))
print(howsum(7,[2,4]))
print(howsum(7,[5,3,4,7]))
```

I saw this code in one video about dynamic programming. I have the doubt in the Space complexity of this code. In that video it is mentioned that the space complexity of the program is O(m) since it calls m times the program(recursively).  But my doubt is each function call will return a array of size m in the worst case, the no. of function call will be m in the worst case, if that was the case each function call should use a array of size m then how the space complexity would be  O(m) instead of O(m^2).

Please anyone help me. I am new to this programming field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the worst space complexity will be `O(target)`. So the video is actually right about `O(m)` if it means `m = target`. Simple example, and I suppose the actual worst case is `howsum(N, [1])`. You will need `N` calls to calculate the result and array of size `N` will be returned. Each call will just add 1 element to that array. And of course I assume that `array` is an integer array of distinct values higher than `0`.